# Should I use Stripe or Google/Apple In-app purchase API for selling digital products in an React Native app?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase

Hello I want to implement an app store that sells digital products in my react native app (like in app services and subscriptions). I was thinking to use the Stripe API or the stripe-react-native library for my project but I read in the documentation that Stripe recommend to use Google and Apple In-app purchase API for this use case. Is it possible anyway to use Stripe for selling digital products ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple and Google may reject your app if you do not use the proper API for what you are selling. In app subscriptions and digital products sounds like a classic thing that Apple and Google will want you to use their APIs for but you can always reach out to their support to double check.